# PHP - Highligh selected link

Tags: php, css, hyperlink, highlighting

How do I "highlight" (turn to a different color, make bold, whatever..) a link that has been clicked on?

Example is here: http://www.celebrything.com/
Trying to get the Today, Week, and Month links in the right sidebar to turn a different color once clicked.

Here's the code I'm using to show the results in the right sidebar:

```
<div id="sidebar">

<div class="post">
<h2>

<font color="#333333">Top 50 Celebrities</font>
<br>
<br>
<font color="#333333"><a href="index.php?table=today">Today</a></font>
<font color="#333333"><a href="index.php?table=week">Week</a></font>
<font color="#333333"><a href="index.php?table=month">Month</a></font>
</font>
<br>
<br>

<?php

function showTable ($table){

if (!in_array($table, array('today', 'week', 'month'))) {
  return false;
}

global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT name, count FROM wp_celebcount_' . $table);
foreach($result as $row) {
echo '<a href="http://www.celebrything.com/?s=' .
    urlencode($row->name) . '&search=Search">' . $row->name .
    '</a> - ' . $row->count . ' Posts<br/>';
}
}


if (!empty($_GET['table'])) {
showTable($_GET['table']);

} else { showTable('today'); }

?>




</h2>
</div>

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

CSS can do this.

If a link has been visited at any point:

```
<style type="text/css">
a:visited { color: red; }
</style>
```

If the link has focus:

```
a:focus { color: red; }
```

**Note:** IE7 and lower don't support `:focus`. See [CSS contents and browser compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) and [`:focus`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/focus.html).

Answer (score 1):

If your asking howto make the current page active here is how you can do it:

```
<font color="#333333"><a class="<?php echo currentPage('today') ?>" href="index.php?table=today">Today</a></font>
<font color="#333333"><a class="<?php echo currentPage('week') ?>" href="index.php?table=week">Week</a></font>
<font color="#333333"><a class="<?php echo currentPage('month') ?>"href="index.php?table=month">Month</a></font>


function currentPage($isTableSet)
{
    if($_GET['table'] == $isTableSet)
        return 'selected'
    else
        return '';
}
```

And you will need to add the .selected class in your css and style it to whatever you want, maybe something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .selected  {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```